# JHipster: Login with email + password. Issue with cache

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, authentication, jhipster

I have a problem with the cache when I login with **email/password** in my dev enviroment of a JHipster project. Here are the steps:

1. In a new fresh project, I login with **user@localhost** user
2. Go to account->settings and change the email to user2@localhost and save the changes
3. I logout and then I can login with either "user@localhost" and "user2@localhost"

I use JHipster v4.13.1 and I made the project with the following settings:

- JWT authentication
- SQL database
- MySQL in production enviroment
- H2 with disk-based persistence in dev
- Spring cache: Ehcache implementation
- No 2nd level cache

I made a workaround with the following lines in the method *loadUserByUsername* of the class DomainUserDetailsService.java:

```
cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE).evict(login);
cacheManager.getCache(UserRepository.USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE).evict(login);
```

But the cache is also evicted in the updateUser method of the UserService class. So, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!